# What do these TARDIS controls do?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

In a special episode of *Doctor Who*, viewers were able to pilot TARDIS across time and space... using their remote control. Viewers needed to follow instructions from The Doctor to press the right control.

There were three controls:

- **Dimensional Stablizer**
- **Vector Tracker**
- **Vortex Loop**

What exactly these three controls do?

Comment: Wibbly wobbly timey wimey... stuff.

While the first two make some kind of sense, the last one is really just made up to have something that sounds "cool" IMO.

Comment: Um. Nope: [Vortex Loops exist in scientific research](http://news.uchicago.edu/article/2013/03/04/vortex-loops-could-untie-knotty-physics-problems)

Comment: In order: 1. get The Doctor out of an impossible situation that got too much for the writers 2. get The Doctor *into* an impossible situation and 3. reboot the universe. Or something.

Comment: @Thaddeus Yes, there are vortex fields in Physics, but they aren't in context with TARDIS. Definitely, vortex field here is Time Vortex.

Comment: @Wikis Point 3 makes sense.. :)

Comment: I know that. I just wanted people to understand that sometimes, you can actually find real science on the end of made up scientific nomenclature for television. Researching those fake terms, I have learned more real science that way than I ever did in school.

Comment: The Dimensional Stabilizer stabilises dimensions. The Vector Tracker tracks vectors. Guess what the Vortex Loop does.

Answer (score 8):

**All of these controls were created for a videogame called Attack of the Graske. The only one to have a prior known existence was the [Relative Dimensional Stabilizer](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Relative_Dimensional_Stabiliser).**

The [TARDIS Data Core](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Doctor_Who_Wiki) reveals:

> - Attack of the Graske was a Doctor Who video game of the interactive movie genre. It premiered on BBC Red Button at the time of the broadcast of TV: The Christmas Invasion. It was later placed on the series 2 DVD box set, to be played by home viewers around the world. It also has been converted for [play in a web browser](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b006q2x0/features/attack-of-the-graske), and is, As of December 2013, available on the official BBC Doctor Who website.

**Relative Dimensional Stabilizer:**

> The Relative Dimensional Stabiliser (simply called RDS or, more often, dimensional stabiliser) was a component of a TARDIS control system, which allowed to cross the dimensional barrier (TV: The Invisible Enemy) or, in other words, which regulated the outer plasmic shell of the ship in relation to its exterior.
>   Some of its functions and/or components include a chronostat and "synaptic adesion". (TV: The Armageddon Factor)

**The Vector Tracker and the Vortex Loop were:**

> In "Attack of the Graske", the vector tracker (and Vortex Loop) were operated by the player at home with either the digital remote control or a computer mouse which has been temporarily linked with the sonic screwdriver. If the player chose incorrectly, the Tenth Doctor, who was busy elsewhere in the TARDIS tracking a Graske, picks it out for them.

Comment: Interestingly, TARDIS Data Core missed something The TARDIS Handbook points out about the RDS: "It is an integral part of the materialisation process and is the source of the noise the TARDIS makes when landing or taking off, [as heard by the Minyan crew of the R1C](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/15-5.htm)" (Steve Tribe, pg 80)